# Find the convergence of series of a sequence of functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $g_1,g_2\cdots,g_n\cdots$ be a sequence of functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $||g_n||_2=\frac{1}{2}$ and it's fourier transform $\hat{g_n}$ vanishes outside $[-n.n+1]$. Show that $\sum_ng_n$ converges to a function $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and compute $||g||_2$.

My attempt : As $g_n$'s are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so we can apply Plancherel Theorem but how to use that I  can't figure out. Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is false. If $\sum g_n$ converges in $L^2,$ then $\|g_n\|_2 \to 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be true. Because of the disjoint fourier transforms, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left\|\,g\,\right\|_2^2
&=\left\|\,\hat{g}\,\right\|_2^2\\
&=\left\|\,\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{g}_n\,\right\|_2^2\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left\|\,\hat{g}_n\,\right\|_2^2\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left\|\,g_n\,\right\|_2^2\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac14
\end{align}
$$
which diverges.

Comment: Why 2nd line to 3rd line imply?

Comment: @PRC: because the domains of $\hat{g}_n$ are disjoint; that is, $\hat{g}_k$ is orthogonal to $\hat{g}_n$ when $k\ne n$.